# DistributedMapCache speed

Tags: apache-nifi

How to increase DistributedMapCache speed?
So far I'm getting around 1000 fetch per minute and it's a serious bottleneck.

This part of the flow exists to check if a html template has been downloaded from S3 to the cache. I can't get multiple instances going because on the case it hasn't been download that would implicate in several calls to S3.

EDIT: Nifi is 1.4.0 and it's running on a t2.medium

Comment: What version of NiFi are you using?

Comment: @mattyb 1.4.0. I have edited the question adding that info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of NiFi 1.5.0 (via [NIFI-4589](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4589)), FetchDistributedMapCache will now issue a single fetch for all desired keys, which should improve the performance. I'm not aware of a workaround for pre-1.5.0 versions.